# Calculate the annual total for last year in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can I **calculate the annual total for the last year**? Specifically, I need to calculate last year's total sales. In this way, if I add to this another measure with the sales of the current year (and I am filtering by months) I will get the accumulated of last year and so far this one.

I give you an example to make it clearer: what I am looking for is to **filter with a slicer by February 2022** and obtain as a result of the measure: **the accumulated sum of all 2021, January 2022 and February 2022**.

Here's what I've done

```html
total_sales = 

VAR sales_last_year =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_sale_order[sales_amount]),
    DATEADD(dim_date[formatted_date], -1, YEAR),
    REMOVEFILTERS(dim_date[month_name])
)

VAR sales_current_year =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_sale_order[sales_amount]),
    DATESYTD(dim_date[formatted_date])
)

RETURN sales_last_year + sales_current_year
```

However, REMOVEFILTERS doesn't work.

In case it is useful to you, this is the structure of the tables I am using:

[dim_date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORTkw.png)

[fact_sale_order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4d3O.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below calculation for previous year total:

VAR sales_last_year =
CALCULATE(
SUM(fact_sale_order[sales_amount]),
PREVIOUSYEAR(dim_date[formatted_date]),
REMOVEFILTERS(dim_date[month_name])
)